# Finding jordan basis

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

[image]

This matrix isn't diagonizable how would I find the third value?

Comment: You're following the wrong way in part (b). Your approach finds the eigenvectors rather than Jordan basis. It seems that you are not understanding the concept: when we talk about Jordan canonical form, we are exactly trying to tackle those matrices that aren't diagonizable. So it's not a real question "This matrix isn't diagonizable how would I find the third value?". You may want to read your textbook more carefully.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here or on your own book:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

In your case the **Jordan canonical form** for A should be:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$

NOTE

When A is not diagonalizable J-form is the best we can do to approach at the diagonal form

$J$ is obtained by $A$ from a similarity transfomation $$P^{-1}AP=J$$

$P$ can be founb solving the system $$AP=PJ$$